# Direct to Specific Route when meteor auto refreshes

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Im using meteor + Iron Router and I would like to handle (in the onbefore web hook) the case where meteor auto refreshes all connected clients and redirect to the home route ('/').

Is there a flag to determine when a refresh is caused by meteor live updating vs a client triggered refresh?

Comment: not sure I totally get the difference between live updating and client triggered refresh, but it seems you could just put  `Route.go('/')` in `startup` on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An auto-refresh triggered by a code change leaves Session variable values in-tact, whereas a client-triggered refresh will reset them all to null. So, if I understand you correctly, you could check for the presence of a Session variable in the [Meteor.startup callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_startup) on the client and call Route.go('/') if it's null. Example:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        if (!Session.get('keyKnownToHaveValue')) {
            Route.go('/');
        }
    });
}
```